# How to add double quotes using logformat in Squid

Tags: squid

I am using Squid 3.5 using the logformat attribute.

I would like to add double quotes around a field. The documentation states the following:

```
% ["|[|'|#] [-] [[0]width] [{argument}] formatcode

    "   output in quoted string format
    [   output in squid text log format as used by log_mime_hdrs
    #   output in URL quoted format
    '   output as-is
```

I have tried the following and various other things:

```
logformat some someId=%"{someID}>h
access_log /some/path some
```

but I am unable to get the value of someID to be in double qoutes. Where am I going wrong? The documentation is not very clear and I can't find any examples of using the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple as:

```
logformat some someId="%{someID}>h"
access_log /some/path some
```

This worked for me.